# How do I create a vsftpd server using docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vsftpd

I'm using powershell to create the docker container so I found a dockerfile and tried to build the image using the dockerfile so I can create my docker container and once it ran it gave me this error "COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder246732598/vsftpd.conf: no such file or directory". Also how do I create the docker container with ftp server once this works?

This is what is in my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

ARG USER_ID=14
ARG GROUP_ID=50

MAINTAINER Fer Uria <fauria@gmail.com>
LABEL Description="vsftpd Docker image based on Centos 7. Supports passive mode and virtual users." \
    License="Apache License 2.0" \
    Usage="docker run -d -p [HOST PORT NUMBER]:21 -v [HOST FTP HOME]:/home/vsftpd fauria/vsftpd" \
    Version="1.0"

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum install -y \
    vsftpd \
    db4-utils \
    db4 \
    iproute && yum clean all

RUN usermod -u ${USER_ID} ftp
RUN groupmod -g ${GROUP_ID} ftp

ENV FTP_USER **String**
ENV FTP_PASS **Random**
ENV PASV_ADDRESS **IPv4**
ENV PASV_ADDR_RESOLVE NO
ENV PASV_ENABLE YES
ENV PASV_MIN_PORT 21100
ENV PASV_MAX_PORT 21110
ENV XFERLOG_STD_FORMAT NO
ENV LOG_STDOUT **Boolean**
ENV FILE_OPEN_MODE 0666
ENV LOCAL_UMASK 077
ENV REVERSE_LOOKUP_ENABLE YES

COPY vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd/
COPY vsftpd_virtual /etc/pam.d/
COPY run-vsftpd.sh /usr/sbin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/run-vsftpd.sh
RUN mkdir -p /home/vsftpd/
RUN chown -R ftp:ftp /home/vsftpd/

VOLUME /home/vsftpd
VOLUME /var/log/vsftpd

EXPOSE 20 21

CMD ["/usr/sbin/run-vsftpd.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are missing files (`vsftpd.conf`). You do not only need to just copy the `Dockerfile` but also all other files from where you found this `Dockerfile`. Place the files in the same directory where your `Dockerfile` is and run the `build` command again.